# Fluid Simulation Disappearing in Render

Tags: rendering, fluid-simulation

[image]

Basically this issue here where sphere sometimes just disappears. Although it looks like its reappearing after a few frames thats just me restarting the rendering with overwrite off. Tried once and the renderer just continued to create spheres without the fluid animation.

What other details should i add?

Comment: At this point i have to restart the render after every frame so it actually remembers the fluid sim exists

Comment: Fixed, apparently baking makes this work, and i had it on replay instead of All.